# Executing a module through Popen

Tags: python

Im executing a module popen1.py and that calls popen2.py using the subprocess module,

but the output of popen2.py is not being displayed..When I display the child process id , its being displayed..Where does the output will be printed for popen2.py

call

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'popen2.py',"parm1='test'","parm='test1'"], shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: if you're executing python code from python, why not `execfile` or `import`?  is a second process really necessary

Comment: @tmc:Can I pass parameters using execfile

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile  You don't have to use parameters; the script you read in will have access to your local namespace and its vars.

Comment: I have a requirement to pass parameters externally.

Answer (score 1):

After the process completes, you can read `child.stdout` and `child.stderr` to get the data (since you pass `subprocess.PIPE`)

Alternatively, you can use `oudata,errdata = child.communicate()` which will wait for the subprocess to finish and then give you it's output as strings.

---

From a design perspective, it's better to import.  I would refactor `popen2.py` as follows:

```
#popen2.py
# ... stuff here
def run(*argv):
    #...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    run(sys.argv[1:])
```

Then you can just import and run popen2.py in popen1.py:

```
#popen1.py
import popen2
popen2.run("parm1=test","parm=test1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use child.stdout/child.stdin to comunicate with the process:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'popen2.py',"parm1='test'","parm='test1'"], shell=True,
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print child.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: The output is blank. How do I know if the module was called in 1st place..I dont see any error in my code